# Get only the column names with non-NULL results in a MySQL result array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

mysqli_fetch_fields displays all the column names even if there is no result in the column.

SHOW COLUMNS does the same thing.

I'm hoping to find a way to only show the column names if there is a result in that column.

The only way I can think is to create an array for column names called "column_name" and then iterate through all the results in a result array. If there's a result, check to see if the column name is in the column_name array, and if it's not in the column_name array then add it. But this seems resource heavy. Is there a faster/better way to do this?

UPDATE: This is what I came up with....

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
$column_name=array();
$query="SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);

for ($set = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);

foreach ($set as &$record) 
    {
    foreach ($record as $key => $value) 
        {
        if (isset($value))
            {
            if (in_array($key, $column_name)) 
                {
                //do nothing because the false flag doesn't work as expected.
                }
            else
                {
                $column_name[]=$key;    
                }
            }
        }
    }

print_r($column_name);
```

Comment: Well, it would be nice if you could share what approx. code you're using to have idea how to help you. :)

Comment: Arggh, I was hoping to avoid writing a bunch of code that I think is going to be resource heavy and not a good solution, especially if there is some simple function I don't know about, but I'm already -2 so it looks like I don't have a choice. Give me a couple minutes.

Comment: maybe a `foreach` and checking against `empty()` with array keys could work, I've never done it with mysql but that logic works with php. Not my dv btw.

Comment: You have been downvoted because those people (as well as me) can't help you out because you have provided insufficient information. :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: I'm just going to put it out there that after over a decade of doing this I am an amazingly crappy coder. :-/

Answer (score 1):

As an example, let's consider the following table `empty_columns`:

```
id  col1    col2    col3    col4
---------------------------------
1   1       NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   1       1       NULL    NULL
4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   NULL    1       NULL    NULL
6   1       NULL    NULL    1
7   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

If I understand your question correct, you want to end up with `['col1', 'col2', 'col4']` as a result, since those are the only columns that contain at least one value. So `col3` is not in there since it contains only NULL values.

If you would run the following query:

```
select 
    max(col1) as col1, 
    max(col2) as col2, 
    max(col3) as col3, 
    max(col4) as col4 
from empty_columns
```

You would get a result with a single row, where only `col3` contains NULL. Then it is just a matter of looping over the columns and checking for NULL values, and you've got your result...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood something... Let's assume in general. Table (`names`) structure:

**id  | name                | data**

1   | RandomName2 | 45820

2   |                           | 45821

3   | RandomName3 | 45822

4   |                           | 45823

5   | RandomName5 | 45824

EDITED (better query solution):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name != """;
$result = $db->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            echo 'ID: '.$row['id'].' '.$row['name'].' '.$row['data'].'<br>';
}
else
    echo '0 results';
```

**Old one:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names";
$result = $db->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if (!empty($row['name'])) // All rows with empty values in 'name' column will be ignored.
            echo 'ID: '.$row['id'].' '.$row['name'].' '.$row['data'].'<br>';
    }
}
else
    echo '0 results';*
```

Comment: that's a bit greedy, isn't it. What if that table contains thousands of rows? You fetch the entire table just to check for empty values...